# Liquibase error for Quartz Scheduler sql script

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, liquibase

I am working on a Spring Boot project where i have to configure quartz scheduler.
Required quartz scheduler tables are built in tables_mysql.sql file, below are the first lines where i found a problem :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS QRTZ_PAUSED_TRIGGER_GRPS;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS QRTZ_SCHEDULER_STATE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS QRTZ_LOCKS;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS QRTZ_SIMPROP_TRIGGERS;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS QRTZ_BLOB_TRIGGERS;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS QRTZ_TRIGGERS;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS;
```

The liquibase YAML file is the following,

[image: db.changelog-master.yaml]

When i run the application, the following error is displayed:

```
08:31:15.153 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR liquibase - classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml: classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml::4::marouane: Change Set classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml::4::marouane failed.  Error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS QRTZ_PAUSED_TRIGGER_GRPS;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS QRTZ_SCHEDUL' at line 2
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS QRTZ_PAUSED_TRIGGER_GRPS;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS QRTZ_SCHEDUL' at line 2
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:316)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:122)
```

Please help me resolve the problem, thank you

Comment: Try adding backticks to the table names in the sql file.

Comment: backticks didn't work

Comment: I don't think that \nGO is the correct end delimiter for mysql. I think you want ; as the delimiter.

Comment: thank you @SteveDonie you saved my day